# How can I upload a base64 image string as if it is a file

Tags: javascript

I have an image in the form of a base64 string (extracted from a canvas).

I want to upload it to the server as an image file - as if the user had selected the image from their drive.

I don't want to post it as a string and convert it on the server unless I have to. (I'd have to write a new process for it; I already have one for handling a file upload.)

Is this possible?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24785136/2182767 - check this one. Blob can be submitted with request